# Proving $\sum \limits_{i=1}^k n_i^2 \le n^2 -(k-1)(2n-k) $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, inequality

Given, $\sum \limits_{i=1}^k n_i = n$ and $n_i \ge 1$. Prove that $$\sum \limits_{i=1}^k n_i^2 \le n^2 -(k-1)(2n-k) $$

I am facing some problems in understanding the following step of [this](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Yr2pJA950iAC&lpg=PR1&pg=PA23#v=onepage&q&f=false) proof:

$$ \left(\sum \limits_{i=1}^k (n_i-1)\right)^2 =  \sum \limits_{i=1}^k (n_i^2-2n_i)+k+ \text{ non-negative cross terms } $$

I am not getting this transformation, could anybody explain this in a lucid manner?

Source: This proof is given in [Graph theory with applications](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=Yr2pJA950iAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). Page #23

Answer (score 4):

It comes down to the fact that

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\right)^2&=(a_1+\ldots+a_k)^2\\\\
&=a_1(a_1+\ldots+a_k)+a_2(a_1+\ldots+a_k)+\ldots+a_k(a_1+\ldots+a_k)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\left(a_j\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}^ka_ja_i\;.
\end{align*}$$

For each ordered pair $\langle j,i\rangle$ of subscripts you get a term $a_ja_i$. Clearly $k$ of those are the square terms $a_1^2,\dots,a_k^2$. The others come in pairs: if $j\ne i$, then you get both $a_ja_i$ and $a_ia_j$. Thus,

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^ka_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^ka_i^2+2\sum_{1\le i<j\le k}a_ia_j\;.\tag{1}$$

In your case $a_i=n_i-1$, so $a_i^2=n_i^2-2n_i+1$, and

$$\sum_{i=1}^ka_i^2=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(n_i^2-2n_i+1\right)=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(n_i^2-2n_i\right)+\sum_{i=1}^k1=\sum_{i=1}^k\left(n_i^2-2n_i\right)+k\;.$$

The rest of $(1)$ is a sum of products $a_ia_j$, which in your setting is products $(n_i-1)(n_j-1)$, and since each $n_i\ge 1$, these products are all non-negative.

Comment: The first equality in the last display is not an equality, since it omits the "cross terms".

Comment: @Gerry: Thanks; it was supposed to be without the parentheses.